# Compare 2 DataFrames gives TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, dataframe, types

Compare two DataFrames gives TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

The error comes from the final line. if I print the dfs out, all is as expected. Also, if I read the data from UTF-8 .csv files I have the same error message

My code is:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import datacompy

    
data1 = """col1,col2,col3,col4
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p
q,r,s,t
u,v,x,y
z,a,b,c
"""

data2 = """col1,col2,col3,col4
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
m,a,o,p
q,r,s,t
u,v,x,y
g,a,b,c
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1))
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2))

compare = datacompy.Compare(df1,df2)
```

Comment: The [docs](https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/) don't mention what happens if you don't specify `on_index`  and don't give columns. This may answer that!

Answer (score 1):

<s>That's actually kind of a bug in `datacompy`</s> Not a bug per se, but an uncought error from the user. A quick fix would be to provide an `on_index` argument:

```
compare = datacompy.Compare(df1, df2, on_index=True)
```

[Docs](https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/#things-that-are-happening-behind-the-scenes) mention that

> You can pass in `on_index=True` instead of `join_columns` to join on the index instead.

Comment: All working OK with your suggestion. Thank you!